# how to test extension classes with a build script

Tags: java, unit-testing, build, classloader

I have created a module for deploying as a JDK extension using [Java Extension Mechanism](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java%20Extension%20Mechanism); and I am building the module using ANT.

Is there any way for me to run my unit tests (using TestNG) during build process on them?

The problem is that there are two types of tests for this module:

- feature tests which can be tested using normal usage of TestNG. (well I don't have any problem with this unit tests).
- tests for SPI classes which can be only done after deploying the jar file as an extension (so bootstrap class-loader) can see them.

Any suggestion? 
I can change the build script to Gradle too, but I don't think that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## General Answer

The second type of tests you are mentioning are integration tests. These are always are a bit harder to write because they require the correct setup of the environment your application lives in. Generally, three steps are necessary:

1. Setup environment (e.g. run database install scripts)
2. Run integration tests
3. Clean up everything from step 1

You have to make a decision if you want to execute steps 1 and 3 in the build script or if you want to code it in the test class, depending on what fits your needs. For example you might find that one approach is cleaner and more portable.

## Solution for your case

In your case step "1 - Setup environment" requires that you fork a new Java VM with the `java.ext.dirs` environment variable set correctly, and for step "3 - clean up" you just make sure that the forked JVM terminates. Your build file will look like this:

1. Compile main code
2. Compile test code
3. Run unit tests (your type one)
4. Fork new VM to run integration tests.

If you choose to do this in Ant, "run integration tests" would look something like this:

```
<target name="extensionIntegrationTest">
  <java classname="your.integration.TestClass" fork="true" failonerror="true">
    <classpath refid="..." />
    <arg value="..." />
    <!-- ... more parameters -->
    <jvmarg value="-Djava.ext.dirs=path/to/your/extension.jar"/
  </java>
</target>
```

Also look at the documentation of the Ant [Java](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task. If you are switching to Gradle (generally a really good idea) you can make use of Gradle's deep [Ant integration](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html) or use the [`JavaExec` task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).

In this case I would recommend using your build file to run the test, but if you want to have evrything in your Java code, and fork a new JVM from your test class you would use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Among other things this will require to read `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.